# How to stop html 5 video playing when video tag have class?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to stop video playing when it has class.

```
<video controls id="video22" class="lity-hide">
    <source src="video/VID_22210517_233643_359_x264.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Stop video playing when it has class "lity-hide"

Comment: How does that class get added to the element?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just want video should not play when this tag has class!

Comment: But the video doesn't start by default, does it? Should all video's be stopped after loading the page that have the class?

Comment: I am trying to create a lightbox, the lightbox is working properly but the video not stoping when lightbox closed. here is the link: http://rankonone.com/dev/acanto-final/html-test3/videos.php

Comment: What library are you using for lightbox? Could you add the code that you use to create the lightbox?

Comment: I am using lity.js. I downloaded it from here: https://sorgalla.com/lity/
I am sorry the last link was incorrect, Please check this: https://www.rankonone.com/dev/acanto-final/html-test4/videos.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the close event to pause all videos. Add the following snippet to your javascript file:

```
$(document).on('lity:close', function() {
    $('video').trigger('pause');
});
```

Comment: Great! Could you mark it as answer/update so other people can find this solution? @KaranKcoresys